# Tool for slicing app into microservices

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, microservices

We've refactored our code a bit and I feel that we could separate some parts of our app into microservices. However it would be helpful to use a tool that would show me a graph of references between parts (directories) of our app.

Our app is in Ruby on Rails.

I know that I won't get 100% coverage of coupling between modules since ruby is a dynamic language... any graph would be useful though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could start using the model dependency diagram from RubyMine: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/ruby/2016.2/viewing-model-dependency-diagram.html

Another tool which includes controller dependencies is https://github.com/preston/railroady

Comment: Cool. Just checked out the RubyMine tool and it generated a UML diagram of our code. Thanks buddy!